# Doctrine Orm Module Pdo doesnt get correct parameters for database when accessing website or console after Aws Beanstalk deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdo, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am working through deploying a Zf2 app with Doctrine on Aws Beanstalk.  Composer is running and setting up everything and afterwards I run a symfony console command to generate the databases and schemas using the parameters specified in my config.  I followed the examples out of here to get the rds params for the configuration.

http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/24/how-to-deploy-safe-zf-2-applications-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/

All this works up to accessing the website.  At which point it gives me a Pdo error accessing the database.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
No such file or directory' in
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43 Stack
trace: #0
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43):
PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array) #
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45):
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username',
'password', Array) #2
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360):
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'username', 'password', Array) #3
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429):
Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() #4
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389):
Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() #5
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/C in
```

The zf2 app is apigility.  After deployment if I log into the server and run the php command

```
php public/index.php development enable
```

It will produce the same error as the frontend website.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
No such file or directory' in
/var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
```

I am setting up the database schemas through console commands that are in the aws config. This does setup the correct database and runs the schema and data import.

.ebextensions/composer.config

```
container_commands:
  01installDev:
  command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar install --dev"
  02makeDatabase:
  command: "/usr/bin/php /var/app/ondeck/cwg.php database:create"
  03createDatabase:
  command: "/usr/bin/php /var/app/ondeck/cwg.php database:fresh"
```

config/autoload/database.global.php

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOMySql\\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
                'port'     => $_SERVER['RDS_PORT'],
                'user'     => $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
                'password' => $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
                'dbname'   => 'api_default',
            ),
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

When I run the console commands I am just creating a doctrine instance with the parameters in these files, that is the only difference from the zf2 app, but I do get the correct params.

Trying to debug this I dumped the $options and $pdo variables inside a doctrine orm module factory.
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/DoctrineORMModule/Service/DBALConnectionFactory.php

```
var_dump($options);die();
object(DoctrineORMModule\Options\DBALConnection)#369 (8) { ["configuration":protected]=>
string(11) "orm_default" ["eventmanager":protected]=> string(11) "orm_default
["pdo":protected]=> NULL ["driverClass":protected]=> string(36)
"Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver" ["wrapperClass":protected]=> NULL
["params":protected]=> array(5) { 
      ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" 
      ["port"]=> string(4) "3306" 
      ["user"]=> string(8) "username" 
      ["password"]=> string(8) "password" 
      ["dbname"]=>string(8) "database" 
} ["doctrineTypeMappings":protected]=> array(0) {
["__strictMode__":protected]=> bool(true) } 

var_dump($pdo);die();
NULL
```

The parameters that are being used are the default doctrine parameters.  I dont know if this is to early in the process if zf2 hasn't loaded the config files but I haven't found any other places related to the connection that will var_dump before the error.  What am I doing wrong either in my aws configuration setup, or firewall rules between the rds servers and the api (which I assumed beanstalk configured for you since it set everything up), or not doing my zf2 configuration correctly?  Any help is appreciated.

### edit

I moved the var_dump further down to line 60

```
var_dump($connection->getParams());die();
array(8) { ["driverClass"]=> string(36) "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver
["wrapperClass"]=> NULL ["pdo"]=> NULL ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port"]=>
string(4) "3306" ["user"]=> string(8) "username" ["password"]=> string(8) "password
["dbname"]=> string(8) "database" }
```

I think this pretty well shows that Doctrine does not see my configuration at all and somehow I am doing something or not doing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow inside the application.config.php file a static location was set for configuration.

```
'config_glob_paths' => array(
        '/home/myhome/api/config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    ),
```

Once I changed that to

```
'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    ),
```

Doctrine started getting the correct params.